# Loading excel to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, google-colaboratory

I am loading an Excel spreadsheet to a pandas data frame but am not getting what I expect. The spreadsheet is 4 columns of text.  I am reading it into the data frame like this:

```
import pandas as pd
file_local = pd.read_excel(r'/content/drive/My Drive/webpage_list.xlsx',dtype=str)
local_df = pd.DataFrame (file_local, columns = ['web_page','page_text','date','status'])
```

I'm getting back a 702 by 4 data frame but all of the text is in the first column rather than parsed to the separate columns.

Any help on how to get the correct result will be a great help.

Cheers

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at the file... For instance, when you do ```pd.read_excel``` you can pass the columns, no need for the third line... But I don't know. Can you provide the spread sheet (or a copy without your data)?

Comment: It's not clear how to attach a file to this thread.  I'm new at this- obviously.  Could you let me know how to do it?

Comment: Posting online and sharing the public lin here would be enough